# Setting different layouts in the layout-hdpi folder

Tags: android, layout

When making an app, I made a xml file for each activity and put it in the layout folder.

My phone looked like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z0m9.jpg

One of my friend's phone was of lower resolution, and did not properly display the layout and looked like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ha6P.jpg

I researched what phone she was using and concluded that I needed to add a layout-hdpi folder and make specific layouts just for the phone. However, my phone (the one that had the layout in the first picture) also uses layout in the layout-hdpi folder instead of the layout that fit more properly in the layout folder.

How should I allow for my LG G3 to use the previous layout but phones where the layout falls of the screen to use the other?

Thanks :)

EDIT xml is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="top"
android:background="#ff000000"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:id="@+id/activity_game">

<Button
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textSize="23dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:text="@string/back"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:textColor="#ffff274a"
    android:id="@+id/back_button"/>


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:id="@+id/show_unknown_distance_button"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ff59e4ff"/>

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="43dp"
    android:rowCount="5"
    android:columnCount="5"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/zero_zero"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/zero_one"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/zero_two"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/zero_three"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/zero_four"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="4" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/one_zero"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/one_one"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/one_two"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/one_three"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/one_four"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="4" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/two_zero"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/two_one"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/two_two"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/two_three"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/two_four"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="4" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/three_zero"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/three_one"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/three_two"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/three_three"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/three_four"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="4" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/four_zero"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/four_one"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/four_two"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/four_three"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/four_four"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="4" />




</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Could you share your layout xml file?

Comment: You can create folders depending on phones' screen size such as `layout-sw360dp`.

Answer (score 0):

The problems is that you are setting a fixed dp size for each button which will not display the same on different devices specially for those that has lower resolution when you test it in higher resolution devices.

Instead of giving the buttons a fixed size, set the width and height to `wrap_content`for each of the button's size properties and set the `GridLayout` width and height instead.

Comment: Wait so what would I set the GridLayout width and height as?

Comment: @Kinoscorpia first if you want to have a full width then setting the width to `match_parent` will do, now for the height if you want it to fill the remaining space set it to `match_parent` if you want to have a fixed height then set it what ever you want it to be.